# Row-by-row Median of non-zero values of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy [n x m] array for which I want to calculate the median of each n rows, but for just the non-zero values of each row.  I would like to do this using numpy without the use of for loops.  So far I know I have to use

```py
median_array = np.median(data, axis=1)
```

to calculate the median across each row, however, how do I effectively mask the zero values in each row when calculating the median?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ignore zeros when I take the median on columns of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049140/how-can-i-ignore-zeros-when-i-take-the-median-on-columns-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [masked array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html)

```py
import numpy as np

np.ma.median(np.ma.masked_equal(data,0),axis=1).data
```

- Example

```py
>>> a =np.hstack(( np.arange(10),np.array([0,1,0,1,0]))).reshape(3,5)

>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

>>> np.ma.median(np.ma.masked_equal(a,0),axis=1).data
array([2.5, 7. , 1. ])
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but you need an `axis=1` argument to match the desired output of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept @Sarthak's answer, it covers it - just wanted to add that people should avoid `np.median` here and provide another example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
print(a)
print(np.median(a, axis=1))
# this answers the question:
print(np.ma.masked_equal(a, 0))
print(np.ma.median(np.ma.masked_equal(a, 0), axis=1))

# you can't just use np.median
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
try:
    print(np.median(np.ma.masked_equal(a, 0), axis=1))
except Warning as w:
    print(w)
```

Result:

```
[[1 2 3 0]
 [4 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[1.5 2.  0. ]
[[1 2 3 --]
 [4 4 -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]]
[2.0 4.0 --]
Warning: 'partition' will ignore the 'mask' of the MaskedArray.
```